# How to use decorator in rails correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, draper

I'm newbie in using decorators and I need your help to understand how to use it right and what am I doing wrong.

**book_decorator.rb**

```
class BookDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all

  def in_users_list?(user)
    if user.books.exists?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

**views/books/index.html.slim**

```
- if book.in_users_list?(current_user)
  - button_text = 'I've read this book'
... #depict some buttons and links
```

**books_controller.rb**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  expose(:book, attributes: :book_params, finder_parameter: :id)
  expose_decorated(:book, decorator: BookDecorator)
...
```

I've followed these tutorials (https://github.com/netguru/decent_decoration https://github.com/drapergem/draper#decorating-objects) and it seems to be fine, but when i'm on books index page, it says

> undefined method `in_users_list?' for Book:0x007f6f4a0a4a18

I suppose that it still doesn't know that it should use method from decorator, but how to fix it? I can't understand what I've done wrong, please help to find and fix problem! 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just had to add expose_decorated(:books) in books_controller. I thing that it's because I'm using it in index method, so books (not just book) should be decorated